# Issue with Discord Music Bot's pause command

Tags: discord.js

How can I fix this code? What I want to happen is that if the member or the requester is going to pause the music that is playing but it is not in the same voice channel as the bot, it will not be paused.

```js
const guildQueue = client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
const member = message.author || message.member.voice || message.member.voice.channel;
const musicbot = guildQueue || message.guild.me.voice.channel;

if (!guildQueue || !message.guild.me.voice.channel) {
    return;
}

if (member == musicbot) {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#5865F2')
        .setDescription(`The track is paused.`)

    guildQueue.audioPlayer.pause();
    return message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
} else if (!member == musicbot) {
    return message.channel.send('You need to be in the same channel as the bot!');
} else {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the variable you need to get. In order to compare the voice channel, you must get first the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.8.0/class/GuildMember) of the user and the bot itself.

Then, you can easily compare their [VoiceState](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.8.0/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel) and see if they are in the same channel.

```js
const guildQueue = client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
const member = message.member;
const musicbotMember = message.guild.me;

if (!guildQueue || !musicbotMember) return;

if (member.voice.channel === musicbot.voice.channel) {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#5865F2')
  .setDescription(`The track is paused.`)

  guildQueue.audioPlayer.pause();
  return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
} else {
  return message.channel.send('You need to be in the same channel as the bot!');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try to type this first:

```
if (!member == musicbot) {
   return message.channel.send('You need to be in the same channel as the bot!');
}
```

then join the `else` statement

```
if (!member == musicbot) {
   return message.channel.send('You need to be in the same channel as the bot!');
} else {
   const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#5865F2')
  .setDescription(`The track is paused.`)

   guildQueue.audioPlayer.pause();
   return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
}
```

So the bot should recognize your first statement as `if` and return if the `member` and the `bot` not in the same `voice channel`, or if this thing didn't work, just add `else if`:

```
if (!member == musicbot) {
   return message.channel.send('You need to be in the same channel as the bot!');
} else if(member === musicbot){
   const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#5865F2')
  .setDescription(`The track is paused.`)

   guildQueue.audioPlayer.pause();
   return message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
}
```